# How to get Array List from an Object of Lists in Java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```java
public class EmployeeDetails {  
// this itself is an Array List defined in other model as List<EmployeeDetails> employeeDetails
    String name;
    String age;
    List<EmployeeDetails> employee    // How to get this ?
}
```

I tried below but not able to access all values in that Array List..

```
public List<EmployeeDetails> printEmployeeDetails(List<EmployeeDetails> data) {
  return data.getEmployeeDetails().stream().findFirst().get().getEmployee()
  // this is only giving me first list. How can i access all values present in this Array List ?
}
```

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/744/java-array-of-arraylist-of-array you can try this example hope will work for you

Comment: you want List of EmployeeDetails containing all employees for the given input list?

If yes then you need joining all employee of the given input list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the combined distinct list of all the `employee` field inside `EmployeeDetails` class, you can do as follows:

```
return data.stream()                            // Stream<EmployeeDetails> (elements of data)
        .map(EmployeeDetails::getEmployee)      // Stream<List<EmployeeDetails>> (stream of employee lists inside EmployeeDetails)
        .flatMap(Collection::parallelStream)    // Stream<EmployeeDetails> (each details of Employee, which is EmployeeDetials)
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a stream of a list from another stream, you can use the flatMap operator.

```
return data.getEmployeeDetails()
  .stream()
  .flatMap(employee -> employee.getEmployee().stream())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm not sure if that answer is sufficient, you didn't specify if it should recursively get all employees as well as what happens with duplicates.